# Puppeteer: Shoutbox/MessageBoard logging

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm scraping a shoutbox which is limited to 10 messages; it's asynchronous and when the 11th item appears the first one is gone.

I set up a puppeteer, it scrapes the structure correctly as an array, which I dump to mongodb. The easiest way automating this I came up with is running script with the `watch` command and static interval.

The question is how to skip duplicates items in log, items shouldn't be unique, just don't dump the same twice. And there's probably a better way to cycle this process.[attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rcqu.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "...skip duplicates items in log,items shouldn't be unique, just don't dump the same twice?"

Comment: I mean each consecutive run of the script is not aware of if there were previous.
This results in duplicate entries in log.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`db.collection.distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) in MongoDB to obtain the distinct messages from your database:

```
db.messages.distinct( 'message' );
```

Alternatively, you can use [`db.collection.createIndex()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) to create a unique index in your database so that the collection will not accept insertion or update of a document where the index key value matches an existing value in the index:

```
db.messages.createIndex( { 'message' : 1 }, { 'unique' : true } );
```

In your Puppeteer script, you can use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) in conjunction with the [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object to obtain distinct messages from the web page that you are scraping:

```
const distinct_messages = await page.evaluate( () => new Set( Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( '.message' ), e => e.textContent ) ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm afraid I didn't manage to explain the task correctly.
I don't need to be sure the records in db are unique.
I'd like to find a way for the script not to scrape what was already scrapped.